# CS50 get_string error linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing Harvard CS50 c course. When I type `make file` in the terminal it throws me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_get_string", referenced from:
      _main in hello-c42e93.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

hello.c:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string answer = get_string("What's your name? ");
    printf("hello, answer\n");
}
```

I installed `cs50.h` library through this steps https://github.com/cs50/libcs50

I am using macOS Ventura 13.1

edit: here is the link of a cs50 library https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/main/src

Comment: What is `get_string`?

Comment: Aside: How does hiding a `char *` behind a `typedef`  benefit a novice programmer?

Comment: Seems to be `string get_string(va_list *args, const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)));` (`string` is `char*`)

Comment: Actually, it's `#define get_string(...) get_string(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: You need to link to the cs50 library.

Comment: Did you provide a Makefile linking with CS50 lib?

Comment: @LHLaurini It's one of the convenience functions provided by the `cs50` library.

Comment: @Haris, most of us around here seem to agree that hiding `char *` behind a typedef *doesn't* help novice programmers.  It's probably the part of CS50 that gets the most hate from us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LHLaurini mentioned above you need to [link](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/) with the cs50 library which contains the definition of the function `get_string()`:

```
clang hello.c -o hello -lcs50
```

You didn't supply the Makefile but usually you can set this variable which is used in a implicit link rule:

```
LDLIBS := -lcs50
```

Comment: I added the link to the post. Thank's for the answers.